# Center Text Larger than Container? (Without using separate child element)

Tags: css, text, centering

Using CSS, it's easy to horizontally center text in a container using `text-align:center;`, but if any single word of that text is *larger than the width of the container,* the browser automatically "clips" to the left boundary of the container (as in, the over-sized word aligns with the left side of the too-small container, and without the CSS `word-break:hyphenate;` property setting (or similar) the over-sized word sticks out past the right edge of the container.

[image]Any way to float this pic left of my text here to save vertical space? Oh well. Anyway...

**Without** using a child container element to hold the text, is there a way to **center** the over-sized word so that it hangs over both left and right sides of the container equally?

Again, I do not want to use a text container within the container. I could do this in 5 seconds by using a child `<div>text to be centered</div>` with fixed `width` and negative `margin-left`, or with `absolute` positioning of a container element inside a `relative` `div`, but I'm looking for a **CSS attribute** that will center text even when the word is too long to fit the width. By default, `text-align:center` doesn't do this.

Thoughts? Thanks! -Slink

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4Edz/8/) shows three `div` elements illustrating the "problem" and both the following "solutions".

### One Possible "Solution"

I'm not sure of your needs, but so far the only real solution I have found is to set `display: table` to your text container. But that will allow the container to stretch to the needed width to contain the longest word, which may not be desirable to you. If that is okay, that is the best solution.

### Another Possible "Faked" Solution

If you must keep the *apparent* size of the element at least, then you can fake the look by some creative pseudo-element use:

```css
.fakeIt {
    text-align: center; /* what you wanted all along */
    display: table; /* key to get centered */
    position: relative; /* allow reference for absolute element */
    z-index: 2; /* set up for a background to be pushed below */
    width: 40px; /* what you want, but table resizes larger if needed*/
    border: none; /* transferring border to the "fake" */
    background-color: transparent; /* transferring background to the "fake" */
}

.fakeIt:after {
    content: ''; /* before or after need it, even if empty */
    width: 40px; /* the original width you wanted for the container */
    position: absolute; /* need this to position it */
    z-index: -1; /* push it behind the foreground */
    left: 50%; /* push it to center */
    top:0; /* give it height */
    bottom: 0;  /* give it height */
    margin-left: -20px; /* half the width to finish centering */
    border: 1px solid red; /* the border you wanted on the container */
    background-color: yellow; /* the background you wanted on the container */
}
```

However, depending upon your particular application, the "faked" solution may not work. Also, the original element will still take up the wider "space" in the document, it just won't look like it is. That could cause issues. Negative `margin` on the container could solve that, but you don't know what the value needs to be set at, as it would differ with text width.

You mention in a comment you are not familiar with pseudo-elements in css, so you may [want to have a quick intro](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info).

Comment: This seems like a very elegant solution. I like the concept, but is it applicable to anchor tags? `<a href...` ? the whole reason I can't use a child element is because my parent container is a link which is treated as an in-line element and cannot hold elements like `div`

Comment: @Slink--Two things: 1) if it is "treated as an in-line element" then you should not be getting any overlap at all, as in-line elements expand with the text. You must have its `display` setting changed to something different. 2) Even if in-line, an `a` tag can have a `span` child element, and the css for both set to center the text as you want. So you are not limited as much as you think to not using a child (also, the HTML5 standard allows `div` in `a`, however, earlier standards do not... so your `DOCTYPE` is going to determine what freedom you have with that).

Comment: An excellent point. If I use `doctype` of `HTML5`, then I can use a child `div`? I wonder if that is true of all browsers, even interweb exploder.

Comment: the reason I refrained from using a child element was that I thought I could not use a block display element. The `<a>` tag allows CSS attributes like `height:100px;` and `width:100px;` even without specifying the CSS `display` property. // another reason for my concern with complicating the link by including a block-type display element is that I do want the website to be friendly for web crawlers. I'm not up to snuff on Google's requirements, but I'm not sure how it would affect the website's legitimacy rating according to the Google bots

Comment: @Slink--there are no issues, even with older web standards, of putting a `span` in the `a` tag and setting it to `display: block`. It is not the css `display` setting that is not allowed, it is native `block` elements of html that are not. Google will not care if there is a `span` inside an `a` tag, it is done all the time.

Comment: @ScottS Thanks much for your guidance. Also, I'm pretty convinced your original answer was awesomely the best possible solution to my question using HTML and CSS. :)

Answer (score 3):

That damned horizontal scrollbar!

http://jsfiddle.net/sqKU6/

```
<div class="inner">
    aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa 
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: +450%;
}
.inner:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -900%;
}
​
```

Comment: What? You lost me. I was never aware of the `:before` CSS attribute, though (that's cool). I just want a CSS text attribute or other trick! `margin-left` or similar would be no good. ??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this solution:

```
.limited-string {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 90%;
}
```