# Center text even when larger than container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center some text, but struggling at the moment.
This is how my text is currently formatted:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="criteria in controller.productCriteria">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row flex">
            <div class="col-xs-3 flex flex-column flex-center"><strong>{{ criteria.name }}</strong></div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-center">
                <div class="row">               
                    <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="attribute in criteria.attributes">
                        <div class="option" ng-class="{ 'active': attribute.active }">
                            <div class="point"></div>
                            <span class="small">{{ attribute.name }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see what it actually looks like here:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/QgmVmp

If you see that, the **Midweight** item is actually larger than it's content, so it doesn't center correctly.
I used a solution from here:

[Center Text Larger than Container? (Without using separate child element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438380/center-text-larger-than-container-without-using-separate-child-element)

to address the situation and although it did actually center the text properly, it increased the size of the columns which meant they wrapped onto a new line, which is not what I want.
You can see that happening here:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/pwLOKW

So, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to the flex properties :

Sample of modification of your [codepen forked](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bRvmMv)

```
  .option {
    color: $silver;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;/* see me , remove me */
```